# Using Carbon to find the number of date since 00-00-0000

Tags: php, php-carbon

I wanna know how many days the calendar started started. So I do this:

```
$beginning = Carbon::create(0, 1, 1)->startOfDay(); // is: 0000-01-01 00:00:00
$date = Carbon::now()->->startOfDay(); // is: 2016-05-25

$beginning->diffInDays($date)); // return: 736473
```

That correct, right?

I wanna make it possible to do the same in reverse. What is the date when the day is 800000? Is there somethign already for this in Carbon what I overlooked?

Comment: Carbon extends PHP's native DateTime class; so all the native DateTime methods are available through Carbon. Create a carbon object with that base date; then use the add() or modify() methods to add 800000 days

Answer (score 0):

0000-01-01 is not a real date: there was no year 0! The year before 1 AD was 1 BC.

Generally speaking, using a date before 1582 AD as an epoch (i.e, a starting reference point) is inadvisable. The Gregorian calendar was established in 1582 AD -- it can be extended backwards to form the [proleptic Gregorian calendar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proleptic_Gregorian_calendar), but some software may handle this inconsistently.

That all being said, you should be able to use the `Carbon->addDays()` method to do what you're trying to accomplish here:

```
$date = $beginning->addDays(800000);
```